# Latex error message

Tags: sourcecode, program

I get this error message when running a markdown program. I am trying to knit to a pdf and for the tangram package, Lancet is a style I need for a report.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.79 \definecolor
{lancet-red}{RGB}{245,224,220}

Comment: you need to load the color (or better, xcolor) package to define the `\definecolor` command

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  But next time, please try to give us enough context to understand how you arrived at your problem by creating a minimal example.  But David is probably right about the solution.